# Why is my android layout /views moving from there actual place?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

My whole layout gets shifted when I deploy my app on my phone and its different for different android versions and pixel phones .Im using Absolute layout.Why is this happening ,can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should post you code so we could see the problem

Comment: Absolute layout is not a very good layout to choose if you are running on different devices and has been deprecated since API level 3.

Comment: I'll definitely  change my layout ,but can you point out something else too in the code below,My views are mostly spread out in the whole app so I think relative layout should work right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the XML code for just one activity,all the buttons are imagebuttons ive added pictures in so im sorry , but it illustrates my mistake I believe !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/SecondActivityTheme">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/entercellnumber"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
     
        android:layout_x="35dp"
        android:layout_y="424dp"
        android:text="  Enter Number"  
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  
         />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_x="15dp"
        android:layout_y="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/SecondActivity_BackButton"
        />


 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cellnumberbutton"
        android:layout_width="121dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_x="35dp"
        android:layout_y="483dp"
        android:background="@drawable/CellNumberButton"
        
         />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/complaintbutton"
        android:layout_width="121dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_x="29dp"
        android:layout_y="102dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ComplaintButton"
       
         />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/devicepackagebutton"
        android:layout_width="121dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_x="30dp"
        android:layout_y="163dp"
        android:background="@drawable/DevicePackageButton"
        
         />

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/depthentrybutton"
        android:layout_width="121dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_x="209dp"
        android:layout_y="486dp"
        android:background="@drawable/DepthEntryButton"
        
         />

 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/manualtimerbutton"
        android:layout_width="121dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_x="32dp"
        android:layout_y="264dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ManualTimerButton"
        
         />
      </AbsoluteLayout>
```